# Backbone LayoutManager Re-Render SubViews

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-boilerplate, backbone-layout-manager

I'm using BBB with the great LayoutManager for the views.
Unfortunately, i can't find a way to re-render specific subviews. Here is my setting:

```
Home.Views.Layout = Backbone.Layout.extend({
    template: "home/home",
    el: "#main",
    views: {
        "#left-menu-container": new Home.Views.Leftmenu(),
        "#searchbox": new Home.Views.Searchbox(),
        "#content": new Home.Views.Content()
    }
});

Home.HomeView = new Home.Views.Layout();
Home.HomeView.render();

Home.Views.AddEditPatient = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: "......",
    events: {
        'click .dosomething': 'dosomething'
    },
    dosomething: function(){
        // [dosomething]

        // Only Render Sub-View, e.g. #content here...
   }
});
```

I don't want to re-render the whole layout, what would be possible by calling Home.HomeView.render() again, but how can i render only the sub-view in this setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to add to do something like this with backbone.layoutmanager

`thisLayout.setView("#content", new View()).render();`

The backbone.layoutmanager v0.6.6 documentation might be helpful
http://documentup.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/#usage/nested-views

Also check
http://vimeo.com/32765088

Comment: That should work. Tim, the contributer of LayoutManager pointed me to the best solution: Home.HomeView.getView("#content").render(); - sometimes life is so easy -,-

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do this in your dosomething function:

```
this.$("#divToRenderTo").html(new subView().render().$el);
```

Be sure to have "return this;" at the end of your sub-view's render function.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I generally do this with layoutmanager:

1. Instantiate views in your initialize function and then drop them into the view in beforeRender. This gives your view access to the subview so you can render it directly.

   ```
   initialize: function() {
       this.subview = new SubView();
   },
   beforeRender: function() {
       this.insertView(this.subview);
   },
   doSomething: function() {
       this.subview.render();
   }
   ```
2. You can use `view.getView(#selector)` to return the embedded view and then call render on that.

   ```
   doSomething: function() {
       this.getView('#content').render();
   }
   ```